# Passing dynamic arbitrary values in Tailwind CSS 3/ Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I know that you are unable to dynamically generate an arbitrary string in TailwindCSS like `hue-rotate-[${randomHueColor}deg]`, because the arbitrary string has to exist at build time.

I see that it also seems impossible to generate the string in a different component and pass it through a prop to the component.

Eg.

```html
<script setup>
import {ref, onBeforeMount} from 'vue'
import ImageComponent from './components/ImageComponent.vue'
const randomHue = ref('')

function generateRandomHue(){
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 361);
  randomHue.value = String(`hue-rotate-[${random}deg]`) // or String(`filter: hue-rotate(${random}deg)`)
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
  generateRandomHue()
})
</setup>
<template>
<ImageComponent :hueColor="randomHue" />

</template>
```

On the component side, I've tried both `class:` and `style:` (with `filter:`).

Is there another way to go about this, so I can have a truly dynamic random arbitrary `hue-rotate`?

Answer (score 2):

I came across a case where I had to get the arbitrary value from a prop and use it like this, `w-[${cellWidthInPixel}px]`. Unfortunately, this is not currently possible and Tailwind suggests against using dynamic class names [in their docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) (check the **Don't use props to build class names dynamically** section). However, that approach didn't work for me as mapping all the widths aren't possible. I also tried computed properties and methods to generate the class name, didn't work either! So ended up using hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0):

What i do so i can still have dynamic arbitrary values is place them in a comment.

```
computed(() => {
    //h-[271px], h-[552px], h-[458px], h-[364px]
    const heights = [271, 552, 458, 364];

    return (index: number) => `h-[${heights[index]}px]`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did it with inline styles.